# Bug with the EnableRule of a custom button in the ribbon of a subgrid

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have experiencing issues with CRM 2011 on disabling custom ribbon using enable rule in the subgrid. This issue can be found on this thread "http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/54547642-b4b0-405b-a4c3-9df1529c60c5/bug-with-the-enablerule-of-a-custom-button-in-the-ribbon-of-a-subgrid?forum=crm". The screenshot in this thread is the issue I'm having. Is this a microsoft bug?

Regards,
MarcLevin

Answer (score 0):

Could be this: "UR12 improves onchange event behavior of checkbox control" (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2013/06/24/ur12-improves-onchange-event-behavior-of-checkbox-control.aspx).